# R dplyr mutate in a function

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

This should be a very straight forward code, I'm just trying to bind new variables to an existing dataframe. However, dplyr mutate doesn't seem to work within a function. When I call the function, addLocation, the items are not added.

Location data (df.russia_locations)

```
 location    lon         lat
 Kalingrad  20.45221    54.71043        
  Moscow    37.61730    55.75583
```

Bind to itemTest (could be any dataset)

```
     addLocation <- function(itemInfo){ itemInfo <- mutate(itemInfo,
                                     Kalingrad_lon = df.russia_locations[1,2],
                                     Kalingrad_lat = df.russia_locations[1,3],
                                     Moscow_lon = df.russia_locations[2,2],
                                     Moscow_lat = df.russia_locations[2,3]
                                    )}
     addLocation(itemTest)
```

I must be missing something?

Comment: @RonakShah that is the location dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return(itemInfo)` before your last bracket in your function or remove the `itemInfo <-` assignment in your function. If you assign the output of your function to a name, you get the expected printed output.

```
> itemTest2 <- addLocation(itemTest)
> length(addLocation(itemTest))
[1] 5
> length(addLocation(itemTest))==length(itemTest)
[1] FALSE
```